# PTIJ: If I wear a bear head to the megilla reading, must I wear a kippah on top of it?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

At the Megillah reading there were many people dressed joyously for Yom Tov, including a number of people in the guise of various animals.

Must a person in the guise of an animal wear a kippah on the animal's head? How about if the animal "head" only covers the area of a normal winter hat? Does it matter whether it is a Kosher animal being depicted, or a non-Kosher domestic animal such as a cat, or a wild beast?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: This seems like it is based on a real and reasonable question about head coverings (if the worn head rests on the shoulders and not on the head, is the head really covered?) so maybe this isn't just for Purim anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Jewish Ber then you need to wear a Kippah. Same for a Jewish Katz. Or for a Vilde Chaya.